# Name shown according to the user's computer date

Tags: php, javascript, date

I have a list of Czech names associated with days of the year - all Czech people have their birthday as well as a "name day". I'd like to display the appropriate name(s) associated with each day (there is a long list) according to the user's computer date. Before investigating coding this myself I wanted to ask if you may know a Javascript script for this type of application already, or know how I should go about it. This site is PHP.

You can see the list of Czech name days here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_days_in_the_Czech_Republic

Comment: Just use a lookup table, with table[date] => name. Seems very straightforward...

Comment: +1 good question. @JoeW: i think he does not want to create the table by hand!

Comment: Just out of curiosity can you put a sample of it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is one. The page is in german unfortunatly: http://www.web-toolbox.net/webtoolbox/datum/datum-tagestipp365.htm

You may use [google translat](http://translate.google.de/)e to translate the description.